# Uploading php file via php using ftp details is executing php and not uploading original php file

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to upload PHP file via php using ftp details as mentioned below.

```
// retrieve name of the file to be uploaded
$source_file=$site_url."IMlobby/IMlobby".$_SESSION['zip_name']."/".$filename;

$fp = @fopen($source_file, 'r');

$destination_file=$filename;
//$upload = ftp_fput($conn_id, $destination_file, $fp, FTP_ASCII);
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_ASCII);

// check upload status
if(!$upload){
$errorMSG.="FTP upload has failed!" ;
```

Here the issue that these files contain PHP code that should be there on remote server but the PHP is getting executed and what I'm getting on the remote server is just HTML.

Please help!

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? If you upload `.php` files, that is by design, isn't it? What do you want to know - how to prevent PHP files from being executed, or how to rename files prior to uploading?

Comment: say I'm uploading a file test.php and it have this code <?php if($_GET['id']==5) { echo "Working"; } ?> So, here want is want is that I need to have the same php code in the file. and when I pass id via get method it should work.
Just to add I'm having a file on my website and I'm uploading it to some other remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file is locally hosted, do not open file by its URL. Use its local path instead.

If you do not know what your local path is - use $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] to find out.

Answer (score 0):

just name the file with an .phps ending (or better, rename it automatically before uploading)

its a major security hole if you allow php file uploads which are executed by the server. you can read all files on the server which are readable by the httpd daemon.